# CSS: Aligning floated li's centered inside div?

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper join-links">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="link">Whatever</a></li>
       <li><a href="link">Something</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.join-links li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
}​
```

Is it somehow possible to align both links "centered" or "justified" inside of the sorrounding wrapper div?

http://jsfiddle.net/CRrmL/

edit: And I also wonder if I can align them right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `float: left` to `display: inline` to give you:

```
.join-links li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right:20px;
}​
```

You can then use text-align on the parent div.

[Example centre align](http://jsfiddle.net/CRrmL/1/)
[Example right align](http://jsfiddle.net/CRrmL/2/)

Comment: Also, if you want your menu elements to have fixed width you want to add a child element to your each of your li elements and set width for them - since display:inline denies setting dimensions for your element. Or you can use display:inline-block but as far as a I know that is crappy in older browsers... =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through the common margin hack for centering:

```
.join-links ul{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Then you need to set the `li` elements to be displayed in line:

```
.join-links li {
    display:inline;
}​
```

Comment: Wait, the ul is display: block by default. So it streches out to the parent div. Why would you want to do the width: 100%;. Maybe I am wrong but this seems incorrect to me, explain mate! =)

Comment: Nope, you are not wrong. There is no need of the "width" rule here. Removed :)

Comment: Also give it the text-align: center; =)

Answer (score 1):

To align alinks to the right or center you need use text align and display inline or inline-block to li element. Float property transforms any element to a block.
http://jsfiddle.net/CRrmL/15/
http://jsfiddle.net/CRrmL/16/

Answer (score 1):

You can make the links justified like this. Just define a class to both `li` and float first `li` to left and second `li` to right.

[Check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/CRrmL/17/)